# How to convert html into word doc file with image and all styling(css) in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web-deployment-project

I have gone through many solutions which soever I can find on StackOverflow and on Google but nothing worked for me If there is any solution of this I am also attaching my code which I've used to convert it but my image was not getting in word file and even styling.

```
convertToWordDoc.php
```

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Offer Letter</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="padding: 0.01em 150px;">
    <div style="display:flex !important;width:80%;margin-top:10px;">
      <img src="./assets/offer_letter_data/amosta_logo.png" style="">
      <div style="border-left:5px solid black;">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looking at Wkhtmltopdf (who's convert intop html too) ?

Comment: I actually don't have any idea how to achieve this so I'll also try to go through wkhtmltopdf